# Google Maps activity crashing when using GPS

Tags: android, gps, maps

I searched answers for this question for almost 2 hours but I found no solution. The thing is I want to create a google maps activity using the device GPS and, in case it is off, ask the user to activate it. The problem I'm facing is that it is crashing everytime I want to open the activity. I'm testing on a real device.

Here is my code:

```
    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.
    public double latitude;
    public double longitude;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pantalla_hospitales_farmacias_cerca);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    private void setUpMap() {

        // Enable MyLocation Layer of Google Map
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // Create a criteria object to retrieve provider
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        // // Get LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))  buildAlertMessageNoGps();

        // Get the name of the best provider
        locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        // Get Current Location
        Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // set map type
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

        // Get latitude of the current location
        latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();

        // Get longitude of the current location
        longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

        // Create a LatLng object for the current location
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        // Show the current location in Google Map
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        // Zoom in the Google Map
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Estás aquí").snippet("Farmacias y hospitales cercanos"));

        // request that the provider send this activity GPS updates every 20 seconds
        //locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mMap.clear();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    // function that opened an activity to turn on the GPS
    private void buildAlertMessageNoGps() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("El GPS está desactivado. ¿Quiere activarlo? ")
                .setCancelable(true)
                .setPositiveButton("Sí.",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {
                                startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        PantallaHospitalesFarmaciasCerca.this.finish();
                    }
                });
        final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }


}
```

The thing is if I use :

```
String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

instead of what I'm using at the moment it works BUT not with GPS, it works with network location. How could I get it working ONLY with GPS?
Thank you so much.

Comment: What is the crash? Please include your logcat.

Comment: Ok, i'll try to see if I can get the error from the real device, but I'm not sure about.

Comment: Well, I'm getting different errors if I selected Log Level: Error, sometimes I get 
12-27 19:59:01.788      883-883/? E/AuthorizationBluetoothService﹕ Proximity feature is not enabled.

others 

12-27 19:59:53.402      465-505/? E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '425b5a98 Toast (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
12-27 19:59:53.406      465-505/? E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '423e2d20 razvitrance.ownnavdrawertest/razvitrance.ownnavdrawertest.PantallaHospitalesFarmaciasCerca (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!

Comment: Ok, I found the errors. I'm getting null pointer exception when 
// Get latitude of the current location
        latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();

        // Get longitude of the current location
        longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

How could I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

When you call [`getLastKnownLocation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String)), it is possible that the result is null:

> If the provider is currently disabled, null is returned.

When you check

```
if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))  buildAlertMessageNoGps();
```

the code after that block still gets executed, so `getLastKnownLocation` is still called while the GPS is disabled. Consider using an else block to prevent that.